# httpclient create a https connection takes too long

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

httpclient-4.5.2.jar

my config below:

```
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

    cm.setMaxTotal(maxConnections);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);
    cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("https://test.com", 443)), 30);

    httpClient= HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

   private HttpPost getHttpPost(String url, String param) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(param)) {
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(param, CHAR_SET_UTF8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    }
    return httpPost;
 }
```

when the httpclient execute the httpPost, it prints some log below:

```
 11:46:33.267 [clientInboundChannel-1] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://test.com:443
 11:46:37.363 [clientInboundChannel-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to test.com/{ipAddress}:443
```

between the two logs, it shows that it takes 4s to open and connect a host. 
I don't know what's wrong with my codes. Does it cause by I don't load the https certificate?
Does anyone know what happen? thanks.

Comment: You need to monitor the network traffic using Wireshark to determine where the delay is.  Until you do that you don't know where to look for a solution.  It could be the server taking 4 seconds to respond.  One serious possibility is that the server does an rDNS lookup of the client and you don't have it configured in your network, so it has to wait for it to time out.

Comment: That will probably be a DNS delay at one or both ends, possibly a reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: on my example, the test.com is a platform ,that my server can send message to and the platform can send a message to my server, not only just req-rsp. Now the platform send a message to my server is so quickly using http. But my server send a https request to the platform is so slow using httpclient. @JimGarrison

Comment: we can't do the required troubleshooting for you. we can't help you unless you provide the necessary information.